# Is there something similar to `$(window).load();` for executing a function after newly inserted Ajax content has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

After I make an ajax request by doing something simple like `$(element).load(url, callback);` there will be new content on the page that includes images and such.

Is there a way to do something similar to `$(window).load(callback)` after the new content has finished loading?

`$(window).load();` works nicely when the page is fresh so that you can show a load animation until all content is loaded, but something simple like this seems to be missing for when content is loaded after `$(window).load()` has already been triggered.

**EDIT 6/6/12 11:55pm:** I think everyone is misunderstanding my question. Let me explain a little better:

When you first load a page, you can take advantage of these two events with jQuery: `$(document).ready();` and `$(window).load();`. The first one fires when the DOM is ready and the second one fires when content is done being loaded (images, etc). After updating the page using jQuery's `.load()` method, I am fully aware that I can pass a callback to be executed after the Ajax is completed.

That is *not* what I want. I want to execute a function after the new content is *finished loading*, similar to when `$(window).load();` fires after a page's initial content has finished loading.

Does that make sense? How can we create an event similar to `$(window).load();` for doing stuff after Ajax'ed content is done loading (*not* just after the HTML has been inserted)?

Comment: Do you just want to display "loading..." during the ajax call?

Comment: i have recently tried the same but its not working instead select the div and put your new html content in it that is alternative

Comment: How are the answers (ajax call back or global ajaxComplete) so far doesn't meet your requirement?

Comment: you can't update your question and expect and expect people to re-answer

Comment: @CoDeaDDict That's true, but it's worth a try. So far though, no one seems to have understood what I am asking. I am 100% aware of being able to execute a callback after an Ajax operation has finished but I'm not sure how to execute a callback after the newly inserted DOM elements have finished loading their resources (images, etc). Can I set up `.on('load', callback)` on the element on which `.load(url, callback)` was used? I've tried, but without success. I'll try again and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to jQuery:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

So, after the DOM has been updated (with Ajax'ed content for example), I am setting a listener for the 'load' events on all newly inserted images:

```
function when_images_loaded($img_container, callback) { // do callback when images in $img_container (jQuery object) are loaded. Only works when ALL images in $img_container are newly inserted images and this function is called immediately after images are inserted into the target.
    var _imgs = $img_container.find('img'),
        img_length = _imgs.length,
        img_load_cntr = 0;

    if (img_length) { //if the $img_container contains new images.
        _imgs.on('load', function() { //then we avoid the callback until images are loaded
            img_load_cntr++;
            if (img_load_cntr == img_length) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
    else { //otherwise just do the main callback action if there's no images in $img_container.
        callback();
    }
}
```

This is nice for allowing content to remain hidden until images are ready. If you have background images that will be showing as background images, this won't work. A workaround would be to load all the images that you are using in your CSS styles into a container that will remain hidden so that the above function will allow you to load the images. Once all the images are loaded, you can remove the element that contains your CSS-only images and that way the browser will render backgrounds (etc) instantaneously when you unhide your content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).load(url, function(){
  //this code is executed after the page is loaded
})
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: That's not what I mean at all. Thanks though. I've updated my question to better explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you are looking for a global approach to handle all ajax complete events.
you can do it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () { alert('ajax completed.') });
    $('#d').load("url-to-page", function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting tip. Thanks. However, that isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated my question to better explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this issue a few days ago and used your answer to your question at the time, but I've since stumbled on the [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) plugin that may be helpful for anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't. You simply needs to trigger the success ajax event that will be executed after ajax is complete. It's enought for you. You don't need events like .load() for specific elements returned by ajax. But you can try to attach the load() event to element like  after html is returned by server but before it inserted to DOM

Comment: Please see my updated question. Can you provide an example of attaching these load events?