# Hide loading gif after ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple question but I couldn't find a clean answer. I need to load heavy images after an ajax call and I want to use an animated gif as a pre-loader. I'm using the follow code:

```
function loadProducts(url) {
    $("#loading").show();
    $('#inner').fadeOut(1).load(url + ' .product-list', function() {
        $('#inner').fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#loading").hide();
        });
    });
}
```

The #loading is hiding when the HTML is loaded `.load(url + ' .product-list'`. The problem is that the heavy images are still rendering on the screen and I would like to keep showing the animated .gif until the renders of the images are finished. Is there a way to know when the images on the screen are rendered?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is ajax? you use ajax first in your code

Comment: add an event for each image onload, count the events and when all have called the call back, Then remove the #loading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use promises to check when all the images have loaded, and then remove the loading gif.

This creates a promise that is resolved when the image has loaded, all the promises are kept in an array, and when all promises are resolved, i.e. all images are loaded, the callback fires.

```
function loadProducts(url) {
    $("#loading").show();

    $('#inner').fadeOut(1).load(url + ' .product-list', function() {

        var promises = [];

        $('#inner').find('img').each(function(_, image) {
            var img = new Image(), 
                def = new $.Deferred();

            img.onload = function() {
                def.resolve();
            }

            promises.push( def.promise() );

            img.src = image.src;
            if (img.complete) img.onload();
        });

        $.when.apply(undefined, promises).done(function() {

            $('#inner').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $("#loading").hide();
            });

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach work fine if I use a static text in the markup instead of a animated gif: `<div id="loading">Loading...</div>`. When I use the animated gif, what happen is that the .gif is showing until the images are loaded and then the .gif is hidden but the animation does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: If the timing works and it waits for all the images to be loaded, but the fading does not work, it just hides the spinner right away, that sounds unrelated and more like a positioning issue, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: The code works perfect with images not so heavy as I expected but enough for my problem. When the images are heavier, the animation of the gif stop. Probably both process, the animation of the gif and the loading of the big images, crash in somewhere.

Comment: Using spin.js `http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/` the code works perfect no matter the weight of the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

### Sample usage

```
imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#container'), function( instance ) {
  console.log('all images are loaded');
});
// selector string
imagesLoaded( '#container', function() {...});
// multiple elements
var posts = document.querySelectorAll('.post');
imagesLoaded( posts, function() {...});
```

Comment: You can also use `$.ajaxSetup` to do the loading mask on `beforeSend` and `complete`

Answer (score 1):

You may try using Image object. E.g:

```
function loadImage(url) {
  $("#loading").show();
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = function(e) {
      $("#loading").hide();
      //ur code to append/show the image
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could add/remove the loader as a class? I have base 64encoded the loader, so there is no pre loader required. This also uses a closure to allow the counter to remember its value.

```
var imgDiv = document.getElementById("imgDiv");
imgDiv.onclick = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var count = 0;     // init the count to 0
    return function () {
        count++;       //count
        if (count === 1) {    // do something on first click
            $('.img-loader-content').addClass('loader');
            $('.imgDiv').load("images/img.jpg", function () {
                $('.img-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
            });
        }
        if (count > 1) {
            $('.imgDiv').slideToggle(400);
        }
    };
})
();
```

Answer (score 0):

the most approach to this is using `onLoad` , so basically after the success call of ajax , invoke another call into success function :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

> onload is most often used within the  element to execute a
>   script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including
>   images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

or use native solution like this :

```
<img src="w3javascript.gif" onload="loadImage()">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

Also last answer of this question is very useful in your case :

[Is there something similar to `$(window).load();` for executing a function after newly inserted Ajax content has finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908562/is-there-something-similar-to-window-load-for-executing-a-function-after)

Answer (score -2):

You can do it easily by ajaxComplete callback, here check an example  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxcomplete

Comment: When the ajax completes, the images are still loading as stated by OP