# $(window).load(function() fails to execute after completely loaded document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have failed to find the answer in the following:

I have an html document that loads a couple of other htmls.
This is done perfectly.

However, in on one of the included htmls, the "`navmenu.html"`, I would like, **after everything is comlepetly loaded,** to execute a script found in `load()` to modify "`menu1`" element's class, which is in the included "`navmenu.html`".

After the `ready()` function, the `load()` function is executed **before** the "`navmenu.html`" is really & completely included in the document, since I get the error message that the element "`menu1`" is not found.

If I pause the action by an `alert()` at the beginning of `load()` - then the `menu1` element is found - since this delay caused by the `alert()` gives time to the `ready()` function to complete.

So, is there a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
    <div id="navmenu"></div>
    <div id="carousel"></div>
</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('#navmenu').load('navmenu.html');
        $('#carousel').load('carousel.html');
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
      var element = document.getElementById("menu1");
      element.classList.add("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something similar to \`$(window).load();\` for executing a function after newly inserted Ajax content has finished loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908562/is-there-something-similar-to-window-load-for-executing-a-function-after)

Comment: Did you wrote the script outside of body on purpose?

Comment: No. Did that made a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery.load() has the following signature (url,data,callbackFunction).

You could try the followind :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#navmenu').load('navmenu.html',[],function(){
         $('#carousel').load('carousel.html',[],function(){
             var element = document.getElementById("menu1");
             element.classList.add("active");
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would like to extend your correct answer. The reason why you need the callback is, that the class will be added before the content is completly loaded (loading external content takes more time than executing the class changing command). Therefore you have to wait till it's loaded. This can be done with the callback method.

Comment: I think I had found this proposition, using a delay but I wasn't sure if that would be the right way. And how long should I wait?

Comment: wait is not an option, because if you wait let's say 1 second which seems to be a good choice, since your page loads under 500 ms  for example, but if you deploy it to a server with slower speed, it will fail, because the load will be after the 1 second trigger of the setTimeout-delayed function..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Radu Toader for the reply.
It worked !!!

*(I am not sure if this is the right way to answer, since it's my first question to the group.)*

I also tried the following, since the element was in "navmenu.html" and had a separate line for the carousel.

```
$('#navmenu').load('navmenu.html',[],function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("menu1");
    element.classList.add("active");
});
$('#carousel').load('carousel.html');
```

I also tried your answer where load.carousel was called by the load.navmenu and it also worked.

Do you suggest that I should use your "more complex" solution instead of the separated line for the carousel?

Thanks again.

Dimitrios

Comment: I suggested that anwser because you said 'after everything is comlepetly loaded' , but your example here, is ok, and will let the carousel load in the same time the navmenu is loading, instead of doing them one, after the other. It is perfectly fine to combine the load-navemenu with that Callback function, and let load-carousel separately